# Apache Camel doneFileName with changing name

Tags: apache-camel

I'm currently creating some route and for one of them I have a problem.
Usually I have a data file and then a done file which have the same name prefixed by "ACK" and this works perfectly with camel and the doneFileName option.

But for one of my route I have to work with a different situation, I still receive two files but they have the same typology, it's like: `MyFILE-{{timestamp}}`. The data file contains the data, and the done file contains just "done".

So I need something to check the content of the file, and if it's juste "done" then process the other file.

Is there a way to handle this with camel?

Comment: How do you mean "two files but with the same name"? This is not possible in a file system. Is the upper/lowercase different? Are they in different folders?

Comment: I've edited my question, it's not exactly the same name, but the same typology. Making the doneFileName unpredictable

Comment: Is the extension same for both files?

Comment: They both have no extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most pragmatic solution I see is to write an "adapter script" (bash or whatever you have at your disposal) that **peeks into every file with a timestamp in its name**.

If the file content is "done":

- Lookup the other "MyFILE-{{timestamp}}" (the data file) and rename it to "MyFILE"
- Rename the done file to "MyFILE.done"

Camel can then import the data file using the standard done-file-option. Because both files are renamed to something without a timestamp, the peek-script ignores them after renaming.

Comment: I think you have the best workaround, I'll try to do it without scripting, only in Camel with a first route that check and rename the file as you explain. And a second route that wait for the done file renamed.